# Cascade not working in hibernate properly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hbm

In the below given code, cascade="save-update", is used for the Course class(bag) associated with the Student class.

Student class is-->

```
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
    private List<Course> courses;
```

Course class is-->

```
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int unit;
```

hbm file for Student is-->

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate.Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="pojos.Student" table="Student">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="ID">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>

        <property name="firstName">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME" />
        </property>

        <property name="lastName">
            <column name="LAST_NAME" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="address" 
                     class="pojos.Address" 
                     column="ADDRESS_ID"
                     cascade="save-update" />

        <bag name="courses" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="STUDENT_ID" />
            <one-to-many class="pojos.Course" />
        </bag>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Transaction I'm performing is simply-->

```
                    Student stud = new Student("Ketan", "Dikshit");
            Address address = new Address("Dm-Road", "Uttar Pradesh", "201301");
            Course course1 = new Course("Core Java", 101);
            Course course2 = new Course("Advanced Java", 201);

            List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
            courses.add(course1);
            courses.add(course2);

            stud.setAddress(address);
            stud.setCourses(courses);

            try {
                tr = session.beginTransaction();
                System.out.println("\n Transaction has begun..!!");
                session.save(stud);
                tr.commit();
                System.out.println("\n Transaction is Commit..!!");
                session.close();
                System.out.println("\n Session is Closed..!!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("\n Transaction is in errror..!!");
                tr.rollback();
                System.out.println("\n Transaction is RollBack..!!");
                session.close();
                System.out.println("\n Session is Closed..!!");
            }
```

Now,As per the code, The Courses table should be holding a column named "STUDENT_ID" with the primary key of the associated Student present for each entry in the Course table.But the column "STUDENT_ID" is not showing any data( all null values inserted).

The query sequence is-->

```
 Transaction has begun..!!
Hibernate: select max(ID) from Student
Hibernate: select max(ID) from Address
Hibernate: select max(ID) from Course
Hibernate: insert into Address (STREET, CITY, ZIPCODE, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Student (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS_ID, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Course (NAME, UNIT, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Course (NAME, UNIT, ID) values (?, ?, ?)

 Transaction is Commit..!!
```

Why is the column in Course table showing NULL values, instead of holding the id's for the Student??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `inverse="true"` from your bag mapping otherwise the owner of this relation will be Course and not Student.

Comment: That worked just about fine, But still whenever I hear this term inverse="true" , most often I find myself wrong footed, the reason being I've never been able to understand it clearly enough as to why and how this attribute works, I just know that it always should go into the declaration of 'many' whenever there is a one-to-many relation. Do help me with that if possible, (some links or clear explaination might help).